# Feeding data back to Android after login is successful

Tags: java, php, android

What I am trying to do but just can't figure it out is after the password and email are checked and are successful I want to then feed back from the php to my Android Studio Java file in order to then save details such as Full Name and email locally to then display in the account section of the app later on.

conceptlogin.php

```
<?php
require "conceptconn.php";
include "conceptfunctions.php";

$response = array();

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$query = "SELECT fullname,password_hash, salt FROM users WHERE email = ?;";

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {    
    die("Please enter a valid email address,");
}

if(!isset($email) || trim($email) == '') {
   die ("Please enter your email address.");
}

if(!isset($password) || trim($password) == '') {
   die ("Please enter your password.");
}

if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($fullname,$passwordHashDB,$salt);
    if($stmt->fetch()){
        //Validate the password
        if(password_verify(concatPasswordWithSalt($password,$salt),$passwordHashDB)){
            echo "Login Successful";
        } else {
            echo "Login Failed";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Account Not Found";
    }
}
?>
```

Java Login Code in Android Studio

```
        try {
            String email = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So ideally what I am looking for is the $fullname from the conceptlogin.php file to be saved to a variable within Android studio after the login is successful.

Answer (score 0):

It returns Login Successful because there is an Echo returning "Login Successful" to the App, what you need to do is create a JSON object in the server PHP then parse the JSON object in your App to retrieve the values you need, an example of creating a JSON object is as follows

```
$myObj->fullname = "value";

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON;
```

As for the email, you already have it from your App so there is no need returning from PHP

You should use an Async Task to accomplish this

An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread. An asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params, Progress and Result, and 4 steps, called onPreExecute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute

You can get the value from the onPostExecute.

Comment: There is no value, to begin with, while it returns `Login Successful` instead of `$fullname`... it also does not properly indicate success or failure. JSON would be better than `String`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have updated the post to provide further information

Answer (score 0):

Google Search 'Volley OkHTTP', 'Retrofit' or even just 'OkHTTP' with "PHP" "Android"  you'll find the answers you need.

I had a similar problem where I made an XML request and I had to do something with the data after waiting for the result. I ended up using a BlockingQueue which blocks on the call resultVar.Take().

Just a quick note, if you do use a BlockingQueue, run it in a new thread or it will freeze your App 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads